# Visual Studio application exited with code -1 (0xffffffff), application is not responding

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

My Windows Forms application run after debug normally, but when I press start button, it goes not responding, and when I stop debugging, output log says it exited with code -1 (0xffffffff). I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community v. 15.7.14. and .NET framework 4.7.03056. 
Can someone find bug or else reason why it is not working?
Code:

```
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Timer myTimer = new Timer();

    bool pokus1;
    bool pokus2;
    bool pokus3;
    bool pokus4;
    bool pokus5;
    double h = 0;
    double v;
    ulong t;
    double hmotnost;
    double F;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string polomer = textBox1.Text;
        string m = textBox2.Text;
        string p = textBox3.Text;
        string nv = textBox4.Text;
        string T = textBox5.Text;
        double r;

        ulong tlak;
        ulong vyska;
       double teplotac;
        double hustotaV = 1.29;
        double m_p = 0;


        int rS = trackBar1.Value;

        myTimer.Interval = (1000 - (rS * 100));
        myTimer.Start();
        v = 0;

        pokus1 =  Double.TryParse(polomer,out r);
        if (!pokus1) //here I want secure "Non-number" inputs
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadejte kladnou hodnotu v metrech, menší než ulong");
        }
        pokus2 = Double.TryParse(m, out hmotnost);
        if (!pokus2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadejte kladnou hodnotu v kilogramech, menší než ulong");
        }
        pokus3 = UInt64.TryParse(p, out tlak);
        if (!pokus3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadejte kladnou hodnotu v pascalech, menší než ulong");
        }
        pokus4 = UInt64.TryParse(nv, out vyska);
        if (!pokus4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadejte kladnou hodnotu v metrech, menší než ulong");
        }
        pokus5 = Double.TryParse(T, out teplotac);
        if (!pokus5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zadejte kladnou hodnotu ve stupích Celsia, menší než long");
        }
        else
        {
            if (H_BTN.Checked == true)
            {
                m_p = 0.0899 * ((4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.Pow(r,3));
            }
            else if (He_BTN.Checked == true)
            {
                m_p = 0.179 * ((4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.Pow(r,3));
            }
            while (h <= 35000)
            {
                double Dvm;
                double Dv;
                double teplota = teplotac + 273.149806372;
                Dvm = 2.75874 + 0.0598528 * teplota - 2.626e-5 * teplota * teplota + 5.22e-9 * teplota * teplota * teplota;
                Dv = (Math.Round(Dvm * 1e3)) / 1e3;
                string vD = Dv.ToString();
                label9.Text = vD;
                double Ov = 6 * Math.PI * Dv * v * r;
                label12.Text = Ov.ToString();
                double Fvz = ((4 / 3) * Math.PI * r * r * r) * hustotaV * 9.81;
                hmotnost = hmotnost + m_p;
                double Ft = (hmotnost) * 9.81;
                F = Fvz - Ft - Ov;



            }
        }


    }



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t++;
        v = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs((F * 35000)) / hmotnost);
        h = v * t;
        label15.Text = v.ToString();
        label16.Text = h.ToString();
        string h_c = h.ToString();

        int h_v;
        bool odp = Int32.TryParse(h_c, out h_v);
        progressBar1.Value = h_v;


    }

    private void H_BTN_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
    }
}

}
```

[Form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcfAv.png)

Comment: Try cutting your program down. There's a lot here that's not relevant to your question (or your problem). See [mcve].

Comment: If `F` ever becomes negative, weird stuff will happen. Check the value of `F` when you change it, to see if it went negative.

Comment: Matthew Watson - Can you please say what is "weird stuff"? I know it will go into negative values at start, but I am using Math.sqrt with Math.Abs, and all varables working with F are double, so I dont see problem here.

Comment: @dejf Oh sorry, misread it. It's if `hmotnost` goes negative you'll have problems, but it seems that the only way that can go negative is if the user enters a negative number.

Comment: You'll have to debug that while() loop, your program stops responding when it keeps looping forever.  Be sure to know how to use the debugger, you need at least be familiar with setting a breakpoint and single-stepping the code.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please describe it more or give me link about it? I am new here, so debugging is just green play button for me...

Comment: Just use Google for links, search for "visual studio how to debug a program".  Lots of tutorials and videos.

Comment: `while (h <= 35000)` - you're not updating `h` in this loop, that I can see. Note that the timer event won't fire while this loop is running as the loop locks the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code that are causing this problem:

1. I don't see `myTimer.Tick += timer1_Tick;` anywhere
2. You are running everything on the UI thread and because of this timer.Tick is never hit. 
   I would suggest running the while loop on a separate thread

   ```
       Task.Run(() =>
       {
           while (h <= 35000)
           {
               ...
           }
       });
   ```

You could have found this easily by debugging so if you are new to Visual Studio I suggest learning how to debug your top priority.